# Progress stops look broken

Tags: css, progress-bar, z-index, layer

Progress stops look broken

I have tried:

- left border: 5px solid transparent
- setting stops with higher z-index

[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HU5b/2/)

[image]

```
.progress-cir {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -11px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid #f3f0e9; }

.progress-rec {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 67px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  border-top: 5px solid #f3f0e9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f3f0e9;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 20; }

.progress-active {
  background: #1e79c3 !important; }
```

Comment: Try adding margin: 0 -9px to your active class. http://jsfiddle.net/7HU5b/1/

Comment: I have updated my jsFiddle, to better show how I was going to use this progress bar. Your idea is good, but it will not work. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this is very bulletproof, but here's a way you could perhaps get what you want: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/aGeok

All I've done here is add some `::after` code to the horizontal bars.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.progress-cir {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -11px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid #f3f0e9; 
}

.progress-rec {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 67px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  border-top: 5px solid #f3f0e9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f3f0e9;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 20; 
}

.progress-active {
  background: #1e79c3 !important; 
}

.progress-active + .progress-rec::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -28px;
    top: -8px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px;
    background: #1e79c3;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="progress-cir progress-active"></a>
<a class="progress-rec progress-active"></a>
<a class="progress-cir progress-active"></a>
<a class="progress-rec"></a>
<a class="progress-cir"></a>
<a class="progress-rec"></a>
<a class="progress-cir"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you very much Ralph!